# Issues with taking input from a form and outputting the result in a Google Chart using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, google-visualization

I'm currently trying to create a spike that dynamically load content for a Google Chart with jQuery and `Ajax`, and the `Google Charts API` but am running into a few issues.

> At the current point in the code, I am trying to use a form to
>   retrieve data from the user and then to output the results in an alert
>   in the Google Chart function call to determine the data is actually
>   being sent to that point in the program. Currently, this is not
>   happening and nothing is being output from the `testFunction()` call.

Below is the code I am currently using in it's entirety...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {
                'packages': ['corechart']
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart(data) {
                alert("WE ARE REACHING THIS POINT!");
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Days', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
                    ['19/07/2016', 10, 5, 3],
                    ['20/07/2016', 5, 4, 2],
                    ['21/07/2016', 15, 3, 1],
                    ['22/07/2016', 2, 1, 2]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: 'CHEEKY PELICANS',
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Year',
                        titleTextStyle: {
                            color: '#333'
                        }
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        minValue: 0
                    },
                    backgroundColor: {
                        fill: 'transparent'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        gridlines: {
                            color: '#AC935D'
                        }
                    },
                    colors: ['#87734A', 'red', 'black'],
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
                $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {});
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

        <form id="formid" name="formname" method="post" onsubmit="return testFunction();">
            Date1: <input type="text" name="date1" id="datepicker1"> <br/> 
            Date2: <input type="text" name="date2" id="datepicker2"> <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function testFunction() {
                alert("TESTFUNCTION IS BEING CALLED!");
                var test = document.getElementById("formid").getElementsByTagName("date1");
                var test2 = document.getElementById("formid").getElementsByTagName("date2");
                alert(test);
                alert(test2);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { formid }
                    success: function(result) {
                        drawChart(result);
                    }

                    error: function() {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I'm not entirely sure if my `Ajax` code is correct at this point in time as I am new to this area. The idea is that I want to retrieve the data from the same file as the `Ajax` function because this is how the function will work once fully implemented into my website.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's start with the `ajax` call...

there are a couple missing commas, which will cause syntax errors.
see comments in following snippet...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { formid },  //<-- need comma
    success: function(result) {
        drawChart(result);
    },  //<-- need comma
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

overall, I would setup the code something like this...

you can rely on the `callback` from `google` to know when the page is loaded
so `google.charts.load` first

next, instead of using `onsubmit` inline within `<form>`
use jQuery to listen for the event --> `$("#formid").submit(drawChart);`

use `preventDefault` to keep the page from reloading

send the serialized form as `data`

last, if `ajax.php` returns valid json in the form `google` likes
you can create the `DataTable` directly from the `result`

see following snippet, it includes logic you could possibly use,
to set default dates when the page first loads

*JavaScript*

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dateFormatter;
    var firstDayOfMonth;
    var today;

    // set default dates
    dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
      pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
    });
    today = new Date();
    firstDayOfMonth = dateFormatter.formatValue(new Date(
      today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1
    ));
    today = dateFormatter.formatValue(today);

    // setup date pickers
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker1").val(firstDayOfMonth);
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker2").val(today);

    // draw chart with default dates
    drawChart(null);

    // draw chart when form is submitted
    $("#formid").submit(drawChart);

    function drawChart(event) {
      if (event !== null) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#formid').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
          var chart;
          var data;
          var options;

          data = new google.visualization.DataTable(result);

          options = {
            title: 'CHEEKY PELICANS',
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Year',
              titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#333'
              }
            },
            vAxis: {
              minValue: 0
            },
            backgroundColor: {
              fill: 'transparent'
            },
            vAxis: {
              gridlines: {
                color: '#AC935D'
              }
            },
            colors: ['#87734A', 'red', 'black'],
          };

          chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown + ': ' + textStatus);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

<form id="formid" name="formname" method="post">
    Date1: <input type="text" name="date1" id="datepicker1"> <br/>
    Date2: <input type="text" name="date2" id="datepicker2"> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: hope this helps, you can find these errors in the browser's developer console -- usually by pressing F12

Comment: Just tried this and it seems to have fixed the ajax call. I'm still having issues reading in the data from the the form though.. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I've been monitoring the console when loading the updated code in my browser and I've found that it keeps returning the error in the ajax call. It seems to be having issues finding the form data / information in ajax.php. It's my understanding that ajax.php refers to the same file that the ajax is running, is this correct?

Comment: not sure I follow, what error is thrown? ajax.php should be the url to the php page that processes the form data and returns the json. it can be the same page but doesn't have to be...

Comment: I'm receiving a 403 error to the PHP file that I am trying to retrieve data from. Are the HTML and JAVASCRIPT code in the edit allowed to exist in the same file? I wish to retrieve the values from the HTML and to use the JAVASCRIPT to send off these values to the PHP to get a response from my database.

Comment: can you post the php portion to the question? yes -- php, html, and javascript can all exist in the same file. -- and `url: 'ajax.php'` should be the name of the file. this is where the ajax call will post the request...